# What test can i use for this hypothesis? It has a continous variable and a categorical variable

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, inference, descriptive-statistics

I have two variables

**Financial literacy**- It's a continuous variable with high and low scores

**Default**(It means to Not pay their loan)- Yes or no (I can code this as 0 and 1)

What test can I use to test this hypothesis?

> Customers with high scores in Financial Literacy default less as
> compared to customers with low scores on Financial Literacy

Answer (score 0):

You can fit a logistic regression and test whether the regression parameter of the Financial Literacy is zero.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression